# Reassembling Silverlight runtime

Tags: disassembly, windows

I'm trying to insert some instrumentation into libraries such as `System.Windows.Browser.dll`.

I tried to use `ildasm`+`ilasm` and Reflexil and both failed - reassembled library causes browser crashes, even when i do not do any changes between disassembling and assembling.

I've managed to change the runtime using simple hex-editor, and it was successful. but it's so annoying.

What do i do wrong? Why it's impossible to reassemble Silverlight5 runtime  with `ildasm`/`ilasm`?

```
ildasm.exe /out=System.Windows.Browser.il System.Windows.Browser.dll
ilasm.exe /dll System.Windows.Browser.il
```

It works perfectly with .NET runtime and with Silverlight applications but not with Silverlight runtime.

Comment: I think it breaks the digital signature. I wonder why the change by Hexeditor is not detected...